# Should I trust zxcvbn with my password?

Tags: web-application, confidentiality

I want to measure current and future password entropy with the [zxcvbn](https://apps.cygnius.net/passtest/) formula.
Is there any way to test and detect if the input on this website is truly confidential?

**EDIT**:
1. I found an embarrasingly easy solution over at super user. In firefox, when saving page, choose the "complete" option so that js files will be included.
2. As SOJPM suggest there is no need to test your real password. An identical patterned one should do.

Comment: **Never trust any site with your password(s) if you don't have to.** But still you may have a pattern behind your password. Use this pattern to generate a similar one and test this. From the test results on this you can deduce the strength of your password.

Comment: Note that password strength checkers are pretty bogus, since they only have a single string to work with, whereas what matters is how the password was generated. If you actually want to estimate the entropy of a password (which doesn't vary over time, by the way), review the generation method.

Comment: If you want to be certain you can download the html file and all the associated javascript code such that you can run it from local files. Before you feed it any sensitive data you can look through the code to ensure it isn't going to send the data anywhere.

Comment: Your password is "123456". I know that because ZXCVBN told me what it was.

Comment: Operation Mayham: initiate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, the zxcvbn project is an entirely client-side javascript app, meaning that, in theory, no data needs to be sent back to the server.

In order to find out if it's sending data back or not, you can do several things;

1. Use a packet sniffer, like wireshark, to inspect any data that this web page is sending back to the server.
2. On the page you link to, you can View Page Source and click through to all of the `zxcvbn/*.js` scripts that are being run. Have a look for yourself at what they're doing!
3. In the case of zxcvbn specifically; this is an open source project. You can find the source at [github.com/dropbox/zxcvbn](https://github.com/dropbox/zxcvbn). If you are planning to use zxcvbn as a plugin on your own page, then you can look at the exact source code that you're running and make sure it's not doing anything suspicious. if it is doing something that you're not comfortable with, then modify it! Or, if JavaScript isn't your thing, there are open source zxcvbn ports to just about every language imaginable on github.

Comment: Firefox and Chrome have a Networking `Development Mode`. If you have this enabled you can watch for any traffic on each keypress.